# Leak while switching activity with YouTubeThumbnailViews

Tags: android, youtube-api, memory-leaks

I really need some help with a leak I get while switching from one to another activity. I am trying to use the YouTube Android API, I load a playlist into some clickable thumbnails and them to play a video. Everything seemed to work, but then I noticed a leak in Logcat.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    OnInitializedListener,
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener, OnClickListener {

YouTubeThumbnailView thumbs1, thumbs2, thumbs3, thumbs4, thumbs5

YouTubeThumbnailLoader Loader;

ImageView play1, play2, play3, play4, play5;

RelativeLayout tempLayout;

public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

String videolist, taal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tempLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tempLayout);
    tempLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    taal = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if(taal.equals("nl")){
    videolist = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }else{
    videolist = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   
    }

    play1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play1);
    play2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play2);
    play3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play3);
    play4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play4);
    play5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play5);


    play1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    thumbs1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.thumbs1);
    thumbs2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.thumbs2);
    thumbs3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.thumbs3);
    thumbs4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.thumbs4);
    thumbs5 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.thumbs5);

    thumbs1.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    thumbs2.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    thumbs3.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    thumbs4.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    thumbs5.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView v,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tempLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText( this,"Unable to initialize",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView v,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.Loader = loader;
    Loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
    if (v == thumbs1)
        Loader.setPlaylist(videolist, 0);
    if (v == thumbs2)
        Loader.setPlaylist(videolist, 1);
    if (v == thumbs3)
        Loader.setPlaylist(videolist, 2);
    if (v == thumbs4)
        Loader.setPlaylist(videolist, 3);
    if (v == thumbs5)
        Loader.setPlaylist(videolist, 4);

}

@Override
public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView v, ErrorReason arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isOnline() == true) {

        tempLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (v == thumbs1)
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.unav);
        play1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (v == thumbs2)
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.unav);
        play2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (v == thumbs3)
            play3.setImageResource(R.drawable.unav);
        play3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (v == thumbs4)
            play4.setImageResource(R.drawable.unav);
        play4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (v == thumbs5)
            play5.setImageResource(R.drawable.unav);
        play5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        tempLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Error: "+ arg1",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

@Override
public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView v, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tempLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    play1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    play2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    play3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    play4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    play5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.setTag(arg1);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String vid = v.getTag().toString();
    if(Loader != null){
    Loader.release();
    Loader = null;
}
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("play", vid);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager CM = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nwi = CM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && nwi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Now this is my LogCat output when I the activity is finished by clicking the thumbnail, so the code in the onClick method:

```
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity      has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f42c50 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked:   Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f42c50 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.122: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f23660 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f23660 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:129)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f3d140 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f3d140 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source) 
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.132: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f291f8 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f291f8 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:131)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f2ed08 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f2ed08 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at     com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:133)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.142: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f2bf80 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f2bf80 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:132)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292): Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f51090 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@42f51090 that was originally bound here
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at  android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at com.reemdroid.tube.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
01-30 19:29:04.152: E/ActivityThread(21292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
```

Am I missing something? I see a serviceConnection, but that should be gone while releasing the YouTubeThumbnailLoader, I assume.

Comment: Anyone who has a clue? I tried removing everything but one YouTubeTumbnailView, but still this ServiceConnection leak occurs. I'm calling release() on the loader in onPause, onStop, removed the finish but still it leaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one loader for every `YouTubeThumbnailView`. You are only saving a reference to one of them (in the field `this.Loader`) and you're only releasing that one loader. You want to release all of them.

One way to achieve this could be to keep a map from `YouTubeThumbnailView` to `YouTubeThumbnailLoader`. In `onInitializationSuccess` you do `map.put(view, loader)` and in `onClick` (where you release) you call `.release()` on all loaders in `map.valueSet()`.

Hope that helps!